# How to Send Check Box value to database in list-view Array Adapter using Volley

Tags: android, post, checkbox, android-volley, android-arrayadapter

I wanted to know that How to Send `checkBox` value to database in `listView` Array Adapter using Volley ? In my project I received some `json` data in my `listview` array adapter, now i want to checked the received data using multiple `checkBox` and post the checked data in database using Volley.

Answer (score 1):

Fetch checked checkbox id in JSONArray or JSONObject format and after casting this array or object to string and send to server. Same like send some string value.